# MySQL losing connection after few minutes while waiting

Tags: ssh, mysql, mariadb, timeout

I have an annoying problem.
I think the connection is lost when there is no operation in **mysql** for a while. I've added a video to make it more explanatory. I tried the solutions on the internet but none of them worked. Please help me find the error, how can I log/ fix it?

[video for mysql](https://streamable.com/253tfw) (Lost connection to MySql server during query)

**MySql variables:** (SHOW global VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';):

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                     | Value    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                   | 10000    |
| delayed_insert_timeout            | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout            | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout       | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout          | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout        | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout               | 60000    |
| lock_wait_timeout                 | 31536000 |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout            | 30       |
| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout | 60       |
| mysqlx_interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| mysqlx_port_open_timeout          | 0        |
| mysqlx_read_timeout               | 30       |
| mysqlx_wait_timeout               | 28800    |
| mysqlx_write_timeout              | 60       |
| net_read_timeout                  | 60000    |
| net_write_timeout                 | 60000    |
| replica_net_timeout               | 60       |
| rpl_stop_replica_timeout          | 31536000 |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout            | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout                 | 60       |
| ssl_session_cache_timeout         | 300      |
| wait_timeout                      | 60000    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
```

**My /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:**

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr                                                                                                                                                             /bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin yes
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: From a MySQL Command Prompt, what is your result for SELECT @@max_execution_time;  Welcome to serverfault.  What is the approximate distance mi/km from you to your hosting server?

Comment: Are you connected through "localhost"?  Through a "proxy"?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you. The result is: 0. The hosting in Frankfurt(Digitalocean), when I ping to hosting usually response time 45ms.

Comment: @RickJames I am connecting like this command: "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -uemre -hMYSERVERIP -pMYPASSWORD" so there is no proxy i guess, i don't know too much about network things sorry.

Comment: does anyone have any ideas?